# Mapping JPA Entity with result of native query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I'm using Spring Data JPA to map entities and tables.

In my PostgreSQL DB, I have a table called declared_location, that stores locations with long and lat. I wrote a sql native query with postgre specific syntax in order to retrieve a list of declared_location, ordered by the relative distance to a given point :

```java
  @Query(value="select *, 1.60934 * (point (:longRef, :latRef) <@> point (longitude, latitude)) as distance from declared_location order by distance", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DeclaredLocation> findAllSortedByDistance(@Param("longRef") double longRef, @Param("latRef") double latRef);
```

I'd like to map the distance calculated by Postgre (column "distance") to a field of my entity. That's where i'm stuck. Here is my entity:

```java
@Entity
public class DeclaredLocation {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private double latitude;

    private double longitude;

    private String address;

    @Column
    private Double relativeDistanceKm;

(...)
}
```

How should I tell Spring Data JPA to map the column `distance` created by postgre as a result of the native query to the field `relativeDistanceKm` of the entity? What is the right approach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use hibernate [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula) for this purpose.

```java
@Entity
public class DeclaredLocation {
   // ...

   @Formula(value = "1.60934 * (point (13,52) <@> point (longitude, latitude))")
   private Double relativeDistanceKm;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I don't want to calculate the distance from a fix point, instead I'd like to pass the long and lat of the changing reference point as parameters of the query. (see my edit above). I didn't mention it in my initial post to avoid overcomplicating my question. In this scenario, i'm not sure that @Formula is helpful.